# Can I find d if I only know the public keys e and N without knowing p and q?

Tags: rsa

Here is one of problems in my assignment:

Consider the RSA public key (e,N) =
 (9292162750094637473537,13029506445953503759481). Find the corresponding private exponent d ∈ Z∗N . Show how you did this.

I feel like it is an impossible task. I know

```
ed ≡ 1 mod ϕ(N)
```

where

```
ϕ(N) = (p-1)(q-1)
```

but I don't know p and q. 
My question is that is there a way to find d if only e and N are given without knowing p and q?

OR

Is there a way to calculate p and q from N = pq? (Although I feel like it will be very difficult)

Comment: 13029506445953503759481 is small enough that it's easy to factor.

Comment: You should also look up Wiener's short secret exponent attack. This is worth trying because a large public exponent like in this example is unusual.

Comment: *cough* https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+13029506445953503759481